# ApexMock - Test method to invoke a Queueable method fails

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, queueable-interface, apexmock

I am using ApexMocks to write unit tests for a method that invokes a Queueable class. My test objective is to verify is the class has been invoked once via the trigger handler. Below is a sample code which you can copy paste in your org as it is to run and verify.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {

    CaseTrigggerHandler.afterInsert();

}
```

CaseTrigggerHandler

```
public class CaseTrigggerHandler {

    public static void afterInsert(){

        System.debug('CaseTrigggerHandler is Called');
        system.enqueueJob(new DividingLogic('abcd'));
    }

}
```

Queueable Class:

```
public with sharing class DividingLogic implements Queueable {
      public String recId;

      public DividingLogic(String recId){

      }

      public void execute(QueueableContext recId){
        // does some stuff
      }
}
```

CaseTriggerHandlerTest

```
@isTest
public class CaseTriggerHandlerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void afterUpdatetest(){
        // Given 
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        Queueable mockQueue = (Queueable)mocks.mock(DividingLogic.class);
        // When the queueable is added
        Test.startTest();
        CaseTrigggerHandler.afterInsert();
        Test.stopTest();  // async executes here

        // Then Verify the queueable was invoked exactly once
        ((Queueable) mocks.verify(mockQueue,mocks
                                  .times(1)
                                  .description('Queueable should start')
                                 ))
        .execute((QueueableContext)fflib_Match.anyObject());         
    }

}
```

When running the above test class I get below error. I was assuming that this error will go away when I put the logic - `system.enqueueJob(new DividingLogic('abcd'));` in the handler class, but that is not the case. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
fflib_ApexMocks.ApexMocksException: Expected : 1, Actual: 0 -- Wanted but not invoked: DividingLogic__sfdc_ApexStub.execute(System.QueueableContext). Queueable should start.
```

I noticed in the debug log of my test run that a JOBId is showing up:

[image]

STACK TRACE:

```
Class.fflib_MethodVerifier.throwException: line 81, column 1
Class.fflib_AnyOrder.verify: line 45, column 1
Class.fflib_MethodVerifier.verifyMethodCall: line 20, column 1
Class.fflib_ApexMocks.verifyMethodCall: line 132, column 1
Class.fflib_ApexMocks: line 256, column 1
Class.fflib_ApexMocks: line 83, column 1
Class.DividingLogic__sfdc_ApexStub.execute: line 8, column 1
Class.CaseTriggerHandlerUnit.afterUpdatetest: line 16, column 1
```

---

Just a thought that may be using ApexMock is not appropriate when testing whether Queueable class has been enqueued. I think I would use:

```
List<AsyncApexJob> asyncJobList = [select id from AsyncApexJob];
System.assertEquals(1,asyncJobList.size(),'One Job should have been enqueued);
```

Comment: As I said in the other question, I’m skeptical that the stubbing interface will work with async.  The doc says it doesn’t work with Batchable and queueables share similar characteristics

Comment: You could use a class that does nothing but enqueue the queueable and mock that class, verifying that it was called.

Comment: ok , If I query AsyncApexJob to see if a job is present , I feel that is also a proper unit testing that has no dependency on data and in this case I do not require to have a stubbing as well. Do you think using a class that does nothing but enqueue the queueable and mock that class is a necessity when it comes to proper way of unit testing?

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that I like using apexMocks as it makes my tests run faster than if I have to do DML but if you have to go thru gyrations to work around apexmocks (and stubbing interface) limitations, you end up not much better off than traditional testing. FYI, some [blog posts](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/11/apex-mocks-and-enterprise-patterns-first-in-a-series/) on apexmocks that I wrote

Comment: I'm thinking the problem with using the framework for this is that `enqueuejob` serializes the object and then deserializes it and calls `execute` in a new context, so `execute` on the object you actually have in your transaction is never called.

Comment: ...So how are we supposed to test Queueable?  It's not possible within the runtime of the actual Apex unit tests?

Comment: I would recommend actual apex test not mocks for this